# What's the difference between element and elementTmpl

Tags: magento2, template, uicomponent, configuration, html

In UI components, what's the difference between setting `template` and `elementTmpl` in a component's `<config/>` node?

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**template :** It means path of the .html template of the **general type of field** to generate field i.e. ui/form/field

**elementTmpl :** It means path of .html template of the **particular type of field (select, text, textarea etc.)** i.e. ui/form/element/textarea

[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-textarea.html)